# Java Scanner ".nextLine" and ".hasNextLine" doesn't grab first line

Tags: java, arrays

So I'm writing some code that emulates the Triangle Solitaire game. The professor wants the board layout entered at once in the following format:

```
P
PP
OPP
POPP
PPPPP
PPPPPP
```

And needs to be thrown into a 6x6 array

However when I used this code:

```
Scanner consoleInput = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("INPUT INSTRUCTIONS: Please input board data via copy/paste.");
System.out.println("Any invalid character (not 'o' or 'p') will be change to 'o' automagically.");

String input = consoleInput.next();

while (consoleInput.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = consoleInput.nextLine();
    System.out.println(line);
}
consoleInput.close();
```

Everything prints fine but the first line is skipped. After spending two hours on this I've lost about 50% of the hair on my head...

Thanks!

Comment: What does `Scanner#next()` do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`String input = consoleInput.next();` is your first line.

Comment: Is there a way I can read from the console without grabbing the next (first) line?

Comment: @user3010203 If _calling_ `consoleInput.next();` consumes the first line, what would you have to do so that you _don't_ read the first line?